# Convert string syntax of an array to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to turn a string as it is literally into an array. Below is a more indepth explanation of my problem.

If you have the below line of code:

```
 <input onclick="retrieve_data('[[\'site_users\', \'SELECT * FROM site_users WHERE id = 8\']]' 'site_users', '1','');">
```

Within here:

```
retrieve_data("[['site_users', 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = 8']]", "site_users", "1","");
```

What I am trying to do is that When retrieve_data gets hit, the first piece:

```
"[['site_users', 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = 8']]"
```

I want to use the below to turn the string as it is literally into an array:

```
var array = new Array();
array = dataset;
$.extend({}, array);
```

Upon everyones good advice I have the below

```
onclick="retrieve_data('{\'table_name\':\'site_users\', \'query\':\'SELECT * FROM `site_users` WHERE `id` = 8\'}', 'site_users', '1','');"
```

Comment: Why don't you just make it an array in the first place? Or at least a valid [JSON string](http://json.org/) so that you can use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Comment: you can eval() it, or slightly reformat it into JSON and parse() it.

Comment: Because its being created in php and placed as a button in html, I had thought about that how would you push an array through html?

Comment: @dandavis so you're suggesting running an `eval` on something that already looks like a gaping SQL vulnerability?

Comment: @PaulS. hey man, i just sell the guns and rope... js is immune to sql anyway and as a string literal, OP presumably has control over it.

Comment: I do checks in the function that handles these queries in php just FYI.

Comment: Please man, don't do that. Never(ever!) expose any database information and queries.

Comment: No worries :) but the function is a php function not accessible.

Comment: @MikeOltmans: Please show us the PHP then that generates the html.

Comment: Please tell me that you're not eventually passing that SQL from the front end to a server to execute, which is what this looks like at first glance? Unless you have some seriously extraordinary circumstances, that's not only unnecessary, but an enormous security hole. Look up SQL injection and make sure you fully understand it if you haven't done already.

Comment: I added an edit to my post with the new set

Comment: Wow, is this for real? SQL in client-side stuff?

Comment: Also another note, this is only utilized in the backend of my website. So admin access and credentials are required which means if someone get s to that point the fact that they have see a sql query is the least of my worries. You can edit all the tables at that point as it is including deleting rows.

Comment: @MikeOltmans the best solution will be to change your [tag:PHP] code.. so please show us how you generate your html

Comment: "[['site_users', 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = 8']]".split(/(?:')([\w\W]+?)(?:')/g).filter(/./.test, /\w/)

Comment: I have edited my code to output this now onclick="retrieve_data('{\'table_name\':\'site_users\', \'query\':\'SELECT * FROM `site_users` WHERE `id` = 8\'}', 'site_users', '1','');"

Comment: Thanks for all the help I got it all figured out and to all about the security. I am very security conscious I use mysql real escape on any query or item going into a query before its allowed to run on my databases.

Comment: @MikeOltmans you're saying if I were to run `retrieve_data([['site_users', 'DROP site_users']]);` there would be no harm done?

Comment: Thats correct certain words arn't allowed... DROP is one of those.

Comment: How do I make a nested object as a string like {{0:1, 2:3}}

Comment: To all who commented on this thankyou for the help I wanted to show the results of your tutelage. I took into advice @dandavis I have changed everything completely around I realized that I could push this [{&quot;table_name&quot;:&quot;$table_name&quot;, &quot;data_value&quot;:&quot;$index_value&quot;}] and do all the table creation (which I had been already doing anyways) into the function that retrieves the data. It keeps the queries from being allowed to be screwed with for one and shortened some code in a few areas